# Local constant function constant on component.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Consider some $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Lets say $f$ is *locally constant* if $\forall x \in X$ there is $\epsilon > 0 :$ $f$ is constant on $U_{\epsilon}(x)$. Lets say that $A$ - *linear component* if for any two points in $A$ there is -- a continuous curve that connects the two points and belongs to $A$.

The problem is : prove that *local constant* function is constant on every linear component.

My attempt : consider some $x \in X$ we know that there is $\epsilon > 0 : $ $f$ constant on $U_{\epsilon}(x)$. Lets take some point in $U_{\epsilon}(x)$ and make it again. We will get some sets $A_{\alpha}$($\alpha$ is value of function on this set). Now there could be two situations: $A_{\alpha}$ intersect $A_{\beta}$ then this is one set $A_{\alpha}$.
If they are doesn't intersect each other, then consider area between two $A_{\alpha}$ and $A_{\beta}$ then there is some $A_{\gamma}$ between them. So will get that X contains uncountable system of unions $A_{\alpha}$. Now if we assume that there is an continuity curve between two $A_{\alpha}$ and $A_{\beta}$ then it should intersect some sequence of $A_{\gamma}$ so it couldn't be continuity.

That's my topology task. I'm interesting in strictness of proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand everything you wrote (there seems to have some typos).

I believe you want to prove that is $\Omega$ is connected and $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is locally constant, then $f$ is constant.

Consider for every $a \in \mathbb R$ the set $\Omega_a = \{x \in \Omega : f(x) = a \}$. By continuity $\Omega_a$ is closed. Since $f$ is locally constant, $\Omega_a$ is open. Now pick $x \in \Omega$, then $\Omega_{f(x)}$ is non-empty, open and closed : since $\Omega$ is connected, $\Omega = \Omega_{f(x)}$ and it follows that $f$ is constant.

Comment: I'm not sure about moment : $\Omega_{a}$ is closed.

Comment: And you are right : $\Omega_a$ is not closed in $\mathbb R^n$. But what I meant is that $\Omega_a$ is closed in $\Omega$ for the induced topology, and this is enough for conclude.

Comment: In fact, I did read your reasoning again and this is more or less the same idea. Here is a way of finishing your proof : consider a curve $u(t)$ between a point in $A_{\alpha}$ and $A_{\beta}$. The set $ t \in [0,1] : f(u(t)) = \alpha$ is closed (by continuity) and open (since $f$ is locally constant) in $[0,1]$  so this should be all $[0,1]$, but as you noticed $A_{\alpha}$ and $A_{\beta}$ are disjoint so this is a contradiction.

Comment: $f(u(t))$ is open because $f$ is *local constant* (so it return open set like interval or open ball)? So if it's so then we should return all $[0,1]$ and that give us that $A_{\alpha}$ and $A_{\beta}$ intersects , am I right?

Comment: Yes. For be more precise, this is not exactly $f(u(t))$ which is open, but the set of $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(u(t)) = \alpha$ which is open. Your conclusion is correct.